# This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key I have tried all suggestion from here

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am trying get the json response from google place api.

I followed all step and suggestion:

- Create Browser key instead than android api key
- Create server key  instead than android api key

it does not work any the steps above.

the message is the following.

```
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 200.104.xx.xx, with empty referer",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Comment: What were the previous errors when you used an android api key? What package name did you use?

Comment: How are you making the initial request?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289380/this-ip-site-or-mobile-application-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-key-with-i

Comment: possible duplicate of [Requesting JSON from Google Maps gives me REQUEST\_DENIED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931513/requesting-json-from-google-maps-gives-me-request-denied)

Answer (score 0):

I have been reading more and the best way to work with place from Android App is Google Places API for Android has a good library to get places and information about it.

to use this I should allow in my manifest file specifics permission.

```
<application>
  ...
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="API_KEY"/>
</application>
```

See more [https://developers.google.com/places/android/](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/)

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea? The docs always say that developers should not put their key on a versioned file (e.g. AndroidManifest)